# in vim how do I make a regex match inclusively?

Tags: regex, vim

In vim if I am trying to match an expression across lines, beginning with a given string and ending with another -- inclusive of the second string -- how should I do this?

For example, in attempting to match:

```
output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)
```

I have tried using `/output\_.\{-}output`) but this fails to include the last "output)" in the search result. If I then use `c/output\_.\{-}output`) to change the search result, I am left with a dangling output).

Another simpler example would be trying to find "January" in a text, including the quotation marks.

I'm new to vim and regular expressions, so forgive me if this question seems trivial. I googled it a bit and couldn't find an answer.

ps bonus points if you can name that snippet!

Comment: Use preview: you had missing backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `/regex` motion by default takes you to the **start** of the match, while you want it to take you to the end. Solution is adding `/e` after `regex`: try `c/output.\{-}output)/e<CR>`, see `:h search-offset` for more information. Or you can use `\zs` to move the start of the match somewhere else: `c/output.\{-}output)\zs<CR>`: this is more useful if you want to match somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Given a document containing

```
STUFF

output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)

OTHER STUFF

output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)

CLOSING STUFF
```

When I do `:%s/output\_.\{-}output)/<START>\0<MIDDLE>\0<END>/`, I get a document containing

```
STUFF

<START>output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)<MIDDLE>output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)<END>

OTHER STUFF

<START>output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)<MIDDLE>output = double('output').as_null_object
game = Game.new(output)<END>

CLOSING STUFF
```

However, if instead I put my cursor on the first `output`, then do `c/output\_.\{-}output)`, 
I find myself in insert mode with everything until the `output)` deleted.

The reason for this is that `c/` deletes everything *until the next match*, it does not delete the next match, as you suspect.  `c/` uses the regex as a start location, not a duration.

In this case, the next match is `output)...OTHER STUFF...output=...output)`.

Answer (score -1):

Use _s at a break between words. So, /phrase1_sphrase2